# How to pass JSON Object to new activity

Tags: android, json, android-intent

I have an application that needs to download JSON from URL using AsyncTask and on onPostExecute() pass that JSON Object to next Activity using putExtra method, but I'm constantly getting an error,which reads "putExtra can only be used to pass strings and not Objects"?How to fix this?

Answer (score 29):

Do this when passing the param:

```
intent.putExtra("json", jsonobj.toString());
```

And in your new activity parse it like so:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("json"));
```

Comment: i dont understand that R.id.param part , here is the code `protected void onPostExecute(Object result){
   Intent startApp = new Intent("com.example.androidhive.HOME");
   startApp.putExtra(R.id.param, result.toString());
   startActivity(startApp);
   //finish();
  }`

Comment: That's just the key, you can put whatever you want in there.

Comment: remove R.id.param and pass any string as key

Comment: hey thats not working , on main activity it crashes application and in the log chat said that it can not convert string to json object

Comment: print the string you get from the getExtra, make sure it's a valid JSON

Answer (score 2):

In the Activity in which You are getting the JSON data write the following code  to send to the TAB activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Another_Activity.class);
                            i.putExtra("key", jsonObject.toString());
                            startActivity(i);
```

to access the data ie JSON object Write the following code in tab Activity

```
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("key"));
                    Toast.makeText(Another_Activity.this, ""+jsonObject.get("Your JSON VALUE"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Your JSON VALUE is the filed which is present in the data. eg "Business Id" 1
here business id is the JSON value ,replace it with yours

Comment: Can you please add textual explanations to your code?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a serializable or parcelable object through putExtra, as JSONObject is neither serializable nor parcelable object, and so you cant pass it through putExtra.

So you need to make either a Parcelable or Serializable  class  from parsing a JSONObject,  then you can use putExtra method to pass it.

The other option is pass JSON String from jsonOjbect.