# Android passing values of JSON object to another activity on list item click

Tags: android, json

i want to pass the correct json object on the list item click in the first activity to the second activity. If i click any list item, the json object from `JSONArray` response should be passed to intent and my next activity must get it.
Here is my code

```
JsonArrayRequest postReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Consumer user = new Consumer();
                                user.setTitle(obj.getString("name"));
                                user.setUserid(obj.getString("user"));
                                user.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                user.setAmountreq(obj.getString("price"));
                                user.setTime(obj.getString("date"));
                                user.setCounty(obj.getString("county"));

                                // adding request to consumer class
                                userList.add(user);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                         /*notifying list adapter about data changes
                         so that it renders the list view with updated data*/
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        hidePDialog();

                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postReq);
        // listening to single list item on click
           listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



                  if(!obj.isNull(position)){
                    //start new activity
                      Intent myIntent = new Intent(RequestFeedActivity.this,RequestFeed.class);  
                      myIntent.putExtra("name", obj.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                      startActivity(myIntent);                                     
                    }   

                      // ListView Clicked





              }
            });
    }
```

On the other activity here is my sample code of the variables i want to be passed

```
TextView rname, rtitle,rprice, rdate, rdesc, rcounty;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.requestfeed);

    rtitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.IDRproduct);
    rprice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.IDRquote);
    rdate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.IDRdate);
    rdesc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.IDRdesc);
    rname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.IDRname);

     Intent myIntent = getIntent();
    //Assign values
    rname.setText(myIntent.getExtras().getString("name")); 
    rtitle.setText(myIntent.getExtras().getString("title"));
    rprice.setText(myIntent.getExtras().getString("pricetag"));
    rdate.setText(myIntent.getExtras().getString("timereq"));
    rdesc.setText(myIntent.getExtras().getString("description"));
    rcounty.setText(myIntent.getExtras().getString("county")); 




}
```

I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632072/passing-json-object-to-another-activity-on-list-item-click?rq=1) but didnt work .Any much help is much appreciated

Comment: James i tried but it gives an error on if(!obj.isNull(position)) and obj.getJSONObject(position).toString() saying the the method is null in the type JSONObject is not applicable for arguments (int).

Comment: Check th edited answer

Comment: Why you are using the JSON data why you are not spliting the data as you have done in onResponse.

Comment: @haresh @james thanks for your answers.I looked at that answer and tried this and it worked:Since the volley response is only visible in the onResponse(JSONArray response) method i initialized a variable JSONArray array; and assigned the value array= response;On the setOnItemClickListener i added the following code `if(!array.isNull(position)){             Intent.putExtra("request",array.optJSONObject(position).toString());
 startActivity(intent);  }` . In RequestFeed class `Intent try {
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(myIntent.getStringExtra("request"));
rname.setText(obj.getString("user"));`

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
Intent i =new Intent(this,ActivityA.class);
Bundle b =new Bundle();
i.putExtra("KEY","VALUE");
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i)
```

At the receiver side

```
Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
b.getInt("KEY") //useaccording to ur need
```

If it doesn't work check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213987/how-to-pass-json-object-to-new-activity)

Comment: James i looked at that answer an tried this: Since the volley response is only visible in the onResponse(JSONArray response) method i initialized a variable JSONArray array; and assigned the value array = response;

Answer (score 0):

**Try to replace this peace of code:**

```
myIntent.getExtras().getString("name")
```

**With this code:**

```
myIntent.getStringExtra("name");
```

Comment: Yes Haresh gives an error on this code if(!obj.isNull(position)) and this obj.getJSONObject(position).toString() .